# What is the most efficient way to extract a date from a timestamp in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql

Having queries of the forms

```
select * from foo
where created_on::date = '2014/1/1'
```

or

```
select * from foo
where date_trunc('day', created_on) = '2014/1/1'
```

or

```
select * from foo
where date(created_on) = '2014/1/1'
```

Under what conditions would the different queries perform better/worse? Which is the most efficient of the three options?

Comment: You'd need to look at the execution plans to be sure, but generally speaking, wrapping the table column in a function like your 2nd and 3rd examples will prevent any index usage, which drops you to a table scan.

Comment: A 4th possibility (to be tested) is `select * from foo where created_on between '2014/1/1 00:00:00' and '2014/1/2 00:00:00'`

Comment: @Brandon: the first expression will also prevent the usage of an index.

Comment: Good point, it's casting.

Comment: How about the 4th one? Because obviously if we are looking for performance while filtering on dates, we will likely be using an index.

Comment: 1 and 3 are identical; `date()` is the function used to implement the `::date` cast. See: `SELECT castfunc::regprocedure FROM pg_cast WHERE castsource = 'timestamp'::regtype AND casttarget = 'date'::regtype`

Comment: @Brandon 's solution is the only one which can use a `timestamp` index, but keep in mind that `BETWEEN` includes both its endpoints. You probably want explicit `>=` / `<` comparisons instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments, your first and third solution are identical.  Casting to a date simply uses the `date` function according to @Nick Barnes.

Those options, plus option 2, requires a function to be run against every row of the table, so even if you have an index, it cannot be used.

Assuming there is an index on `created_on`, this is your best bet:

```
select * from foo
where created_on >= '2014/1/1 00:00:00'
  and created_on < '2014/1/2 00:00:00';
```

Comment: If I have partitioned data based on month, I believe it doesn't scan all partitions right?